# Errors after mounting nodes in LFS

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Trying out Linux from scratch here, not too savvy with linux. Section: [6.2](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter06/kernfs.html)

To avoid entering sudo all the time, I went into `sudo su` and entered the mount commands:

```
mount -vt devpts devpts $LFS/dev/pts -o gid=5,mode=620
mount -vt proc proc $LFS/proc
mount -vt sysfs sysfs $LFS/sys
mount -vt tmpfs tmpfs $LFS/run
```

However, I forgot that setting `$LFS` in another account does not show in `root`.

After exiting from `root`, I could not run anything with `sudo`, as the following error would pop up: `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`.

Upon reading a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error), I entered `sudo -S true`, which allowed me to run `sudo` commands without a password.

On another note, I got a disk usage warning, but when I try to run gparted (which I could run before all this happened), I get the following message: `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory gparted`.

How badly have I messed up, and how do I resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you only have mounted some filesystems. Filesystem mounts are not persistent across reboots (unless they are in `/etc/fstab`), so a reboot should solve your problem.

Comment: When issuing the reboot command, the following error is thrown: `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`

Comment: performing a hard reboot.

Comment: The reboot worked, thank you. I still get error messages saying devd and logind have issues, but they aren't hindering progress (unless there are larger underlying issues)

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark the answer as such (using the green checkmark) so it will be easier for others to find.